# Thermal equilibrium and kinetic energies

Tags: thermodynamics, atomic-physics

Is temperature solely a function of a kinetic energy? If a solid and a gas are at thermal equilibrium at a temperature of 20 degrees Celsius, the solid has much less kinetic energy than the gas. How can the temperatures of both be the same? What is keeping the solid at the same temperature as the gas?

Comment: The solid and the gas would have the same kinetic energy if they have the same temperature.

Answer (score 1):

Temperature can be defined as the gradient of internal energy with respect to entropy.  The internal energy contains both the kinetic and potential energy associated with a system.  So when two systems are in thermal equilibrium we are only saying that the gradient of energy to entropy is the same.  The actual internal energy of the system is not generally the driver of the temperature.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and I'm sorry if I missed something, but what then is the main driver of temperature?

Comment: The ratio of relative change in internal energy to the entropy, e.g. $T=\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}$

Answer (score 0):

The kinetic energy of the molecules in the gas and the solid would be the same if they are at the same temperature. The kinetic energy per molecule is given by the following equation,

E = (3/2) kT

Where k is the Boltzmann constant and T is temperature.
It can be immediately seen that if the temperatures are equal, then the molecules will have the same kinetic energy, whether they are gas, liquid or solid.

The difference is that molecules in the solid are bound by bonding forces, while the molecules in the gas are free, however, the kinetic energies are equal.